# Запятая переносит значение в новый столбец CSV python

Tags: python, csv, libre-office

Заполняю CSV файл, в качестве разделителя стоит ";" но если текст содержит "," то запятая срабатывает как разделитель

```
with open('res.csv', 'a', newline = '', encoding='utf=8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ';')
    writer.writerow([category.replace(',', ''), code, title, meta_title, meta_descriprion, meta_keywords, attributes, description.replace(',', ' ') , waranty, new_price, base_img, more_img, link])
```

если убрать замену запятых в столбце description, то они срабатывают как delimiter, так же и со столбцом category (на скрине не представлено увы)
[image: ожидание]
[image: реальность]

Быть может поможет замена запятой на ее код, подскажите его кто знает

Comment: По-моему всё нормально записывает https://repl.it/repls/LiquidOpulentFibonacci

Comment: @вася быть может в данном редакторе это и работает, но по факту пришлось убрать все запятые и тогда все работает правильно

Comment: Причём тут "редактор"? Приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример кода, который работает не так, как вы хотите, указав ожидаемый и реальный выход

Comment: пример кода записи представлен, я делаю парсер, заполняю столбец с описанием, и если не убрать запятые, то после каждой запятой текст переносится на новый столбец @вася
with open('res2.csv', 'a', newline = '', encoding='utf=8') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ';')
   writer.writerow([category.replace(',', ''), code, title, meta_title, meta_descriprion, meta_keywords, attributes, description , waranty, new_price, base_img, more_img, link])
если я не буду убирать в category запятые, то все разносится

Comment: Но я же привёл ваш код со строками, содержащими запятые, и никаких лишних переносов нет в файле

Comment: @вася да, я видел, но увы и ах у меня разносит, я могу вам предоставить скрины и ссылку на страницу с товаром

Comment: Добавьте всю информацию в сам вопрос с помощью [кнопки править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1144432/edit).

Comment: @вася предоставил

Comment: В чем открываете файл, в excel?

Comment: @insolor LibreOffice

Comment: Так в LibreOffice при открытии csv диалог импорта отображается. Там нужно настроить, чтобы он не считал запятую разделителем.

Comment: @insolor спасибо, опробую

Comment: Собственно, вот: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpV5y.png

Comment: @insolor спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это проблема не в Python, а в импорте в Libre Office. При импорте csv файла в Libre Office нужно настроить, чтобы разделителем считалась только точка с запятой:

[image: Скриншот]